# What platform is my Oracle running on?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've been given access to an Oracle instance running somewhere but I do not have access to its underlying platform. i.e. I have a database user and the database connection information including host name, port number and SID so I can connect to the database using `SQL*Plus` and run my queries but I even do not know whether it is running on Windows or Linux.

I need to know:

(1) What's the platform?
(2) If Windows, does it support `ODP.Net`?

Assuming my database user has all the necessary privileges, what can I do? Can I run a query or are there any views that give me this sort of information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from v$version;
select platform_name from v$database;
select dbms_utility.port_string from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks. This gave me the platform. Do you have any suggestion for .Net?

Comment: @Reza - I'm not familiar with .Net.  But surely you don't have access to Windows registry to do checking described in Sebas's answer.